# Page Control with TableView Example

Tags: uitableview, uipagecontrol

Currently I have a tableview containing 4 custom cells.  I desire the user to select one of the cells.  This works OK using the accessory checkmark.  The problem I have is in trying to make it easier for the user to know which cell to select.  My current thought is to have a page control object consisting an array of 4 custom cells.  Page 1 would should the tableview for object 1, Page 2 would show the tableview for object 2.  I would then add a 'select me' button as a new tableview section.  Taking this approach would then enable me to use the disclosure button in the cells to navigate to a 'more details on this (indexpath)' view.

An example of how to do this or where to find one would be greatly appreciated.
Or if you have a better (standard) way to accomplish this that would be great also.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to think about this.

Comment: pls check answer of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988664/is-that-possible-to-use-uipagecontrol-to-control-the-move-of-uitableview)